# Creating Javascript Object without explicitly defining the keys?

Tags: javascript, object

Today I saw a piece of code which I have never seen before:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = { a, b };
```

This creates an object (assigned to c) which contains two keys, those are the names of the variables, and the values are the variable's values, like this:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}
```

Is this something normal? I couldn't find anything related to this or creating objects this way. I tested it on chrome and it worked fined, but I am not sure if this will work in every browser.

I would expect to create the object this way:

```
var c = { a: a, b: b };
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring has some examples

Comment: I'm sure this question has already been asked. Who finds the original one?

Comment: @nicael what about you? :D

Comment: Yes, I did that! :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is part of the ES6 object shorthand, where you may use variables from the current scope to declare a property within an object (literal) with the same name and value as that variable.

That is, `c = {a, b}` expands to `c = {a: a, b: b}` so long as `a` and `b` are both in the current scope.

The MDN documentation goes into [more detail here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).